# Flutter: type_ahead suggestion box height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
  TypeAheadFormField(
              // hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: true,
              textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                controller: this._typeAheadController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.amber),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
                print(pattern);
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                return Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      suggestion['game'],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              transitionBuilder: (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
                return suggestionsBox;
              },
              onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) async {
                print('hey');
              },
            ),
```

This is the `TypeAheadFormField()`. This is located at the bottom of the screen. And, I think this is why my suggestion box gets disappeared when my keyboard pops up on a screen.

How can I set the height of the suggestion box so that it does not disappear when my keyboard push my screen up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same issue and couldn't find the right solution.

So we made a temporary but good enough alternative:

for each TypeAheadFormField() that is located at the bottom of the screen, make the suggestion box show on top of Field by adding this line:

```
direction: AxisDirection.up,
```

So it should be looking like this:

```
TypeAheadFormField(
// The other params
direction: AxisDirection.up, 
)
```